# Discrepancies in reading geopackages between ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro

Tags: qgis, arcmap, qgis-3, arcgis-pro, geometry

I have a GeoPackage database with a few layers inside of it. One layer, which has about 1000 records, some complex geometry, but no relationships, would not open correctly in ArcMap (specifically ArcMap 10.3.1) with the error being as per screen grab (which occurs during browsing of the attribute table)

[image]

Error Message reads:

> Error reading OID from table. Reading rows has been stopped.Check that
> the datasource is valid. Underlying DMS Error[ST_EnvIntersects:
> Invalid Geometry type] The operation is not support by this
> implementation.

However, the Geopackage is geometrically compliant inside of QGIS and other open source geometry validation tools (check validity as an example). Interestingly, ArcGIS Pro 2.2.0 has no problem reading the Geopackage.

Should I investigate the data further becuase ArcMap is telling me its invalid or does the QGIS OGC geometric checking tools (And ArcGIS Pro) give me enough confidence to know the geometry is valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GeoPackage support in ArcMap is not shining and as far as I know it is not developed any more but improvements go only to ArcGIS Pro.

You can use the GDAL validation script written in Python "validata_gpkg.py" from https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/swig/python/samples/validate_gpkg.py. The script is running all the tests which are defined in the GeoPackage standard. If it does not show errors you can be pretty sure that the GeoPackage is valid.

If you need interoperability with ArcMap some more research would be needed for finding out what the error message really means and if it could be possible to create slightly different GeoPackage that ArcMap understands better. Error refers to geometry type and it may be that ArcMap does not handle for example geometry collections, or that the geometry field is registered into the metadata tables as generic "geometry" but ArcMap wants to see an exact geometry type like "multipolygon". Just quessing but I have seem something similar before.

I guess that you have a support contract and pay for it so I suggest to contact also ESRI. They probably answer that you should start using ArcGIS Pro but at least they get to know about the issue.

Comment: cheers for that ill check it out. I think my actual question and the subject heading are a little bit discrepant themselves - whilst ill need to use either ArcMap or ArcPro for publishing of the data to Portal, my real question was to understand where the root cause of the problem is. Geopackage, ArcMap, or ArcPro....Validating the geopackage helps me determine this to be ArcMap as having a problem - which gives me enough direction to change my publication mechanisms over to ArcGIS Pro - so thanks for thats!